# How to stream AudioIN by PulseAudio

Tags: raspbian, pulseaudio, usb-audio

I'm new and I can't speak well in Eng.
I need Your help.
A few days ago, I bought UCA222 and I need to stream AudioIN by RTSP or sth like this.
I was tried by OBS on RPi, but something is broken.

Now, RPis using raspbian. It should be min.320Kbps audio quality, nothing more. After instalation and properly configuration, RPi will be working 8hours per day. Audio streaming, nothing more (SSH ofc.)
What should it doing? Only streaming audio to OBs on PC with Windows, it should start stream after switch on RPi (in case of power lost)

I <3 You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I did it !
Darkice and IceCast2, working perfect.
For other:
[Here's instruction... Easy strong tool](https://maker.pro/raspberry-pi/projects/how-to-build-an-internet-radio-station-with-raspberry-pi-darkice-and-icecast)

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.